# Por que no me sale la condicion IF EXISTS en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy trantando de hacer la consulta con un if exists, pero por alguna razon me da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no entiendo que quiere decir con eso xD, la consulta en tal caso seria: if exists (SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = "22") pero como dije anteriormete me dice: tipo de declaracion desconocida

Comment: ¿Que necesitas obtener o cual es el resultado esperado de la consulta?

Answer (score -1):

Espero haberte ayudado

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = "22");
```

Otra Opción seria:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = '22'),1,0)
```

Comment: si funciona la consulta, pero quiero hacerlo con if exist al principio, ya que terminaria la consulta asi: if exist (select * from current_products where room = 22) begin <instrucciones> end

Comment: perdon te entendi mal, ya lo modfique ahora si te tiene que funcionar

Comment: la segunda opcion esta brutal, lo que necesito, pero ahora como le agregas otra consulta para que si existe haga algo? y si no que haga lo otro, por ejemplo si existe en la tabla de current_products me devuelva sus datos pero si no ingresar a otra tabla y devolverme esos datos de alla correspondientes al numero de habitacion

Comment: SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = '22'),1,0).
La estructura del if (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = '22'),'Aqui pones lo que pasa si el dato existe','Aqui pones lo que pasa si el dato no existe')

Comment: separas la primera consulta de la ultima con un punto? asi:

SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `current_products` WHERE room = '22'),1,0),(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `current_products` WHERE room = '22'),SELECT * FROM `current_products` WHERE room = '22', SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE room = '22')

Comment: creo que seria asi:

SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = '22'),SELECT * FROM current_products WHERE room = '22', SELECT * FROM finished_products WHERE room = '22')

Comment: SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM current_products WHERE room = '22'),(SELECT * FROM `current_products` WHERE room ='22'),(SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE room ='22')) , asi lo tengo, pero ahora me dicen que operando debe tener 1 columna (s)